# R - add transparency to colorRampPalette

Tags: r

I'm using `smoothScatter` to plot some data. I'm trying to change the color of the density from the default of `colorRampPalette(c("white", blues9)` to transparent red. How can I do this?

I tried:

```
smoothScatter(
  x,y,nrpoints=length(df$x),
  colramp = colorRampPalette(c(rgb(1,1,1,0.5),rgb(1,0,0,0.5))
)
```

But this doens't work.

More generally put, how can I create a `colorRampPalette` function that can be passed in as a function that includes making all the colors transparent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to add `alpha=TRUE` to your call to `colorRampPalette`:

```
>?colorRampPalette
   alpha: logical: should alpha channel (opacity) values should be
          returned?  It is an error to give a true value if ‘space’ is
          specified.

> colorRampPalette(c(rgb(1,1,1,0.5),rgb(1,0,0,0.5)))(3)
[1] "#FFFFFF" "#FF7F7F" "#FF0000"
> colorRampPalette(c(rgb(1,1,1,0.5),rgb(1,0,0,0.5)), alpha=TRUE)(3)
[1] "#FFFFFF80" "#FF7F7F80" "#FF000080"
```

Since your `colorRampPalette` doesn't seem to have the `alpha` argument, here's a manual solution:

```
# Specify alpha as a percentage:
colorRampAlpha <- function(..., n, alpha) {
   colors <- colorRampPalette(...)(n)
   paste(colors, sprintf("%x", ceiling(255*alpha)), sep="")
}
colorRampAlpha(c(rgb(1,1,1),rgb(1,0,0)), n=3, alpha=0.5)
[1] "#FFFFFF80" "#FF7F7F80" "#FF000080"
```

You'll need to specify the number of colors you want in advance however.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the suggestion but I'm getting an error: cols = colorRampPalette(colors=c(rgb(1,1,1,0.5),rgb(1,0,0,0.5)),alpha=TRUE)
Error in colorRamp(colors, ...) : unused argument (alpha = TRUE)

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe I'm running a newer version of R?

Comment: What version are you running? I'm on 3.2

Comment: Odd... I'm on 3.1, I've added a manual solution. You can simply `paste` the correct `alpha` hexidecimal value to each color.

Comment: Run `update.packages("grDevices")`. From the help page: `Argument alpha has introduced in R 3.1.0.`, so some of your packages must be from earlier installations of R.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my inelegant way to create a transparent palette with colorRampPalette

```
## first specify your color scheme

colorRampPalette(c("lightgrey","grey","lightblue","blue","darkblue"))  -> blues

## Then create the palette as you would normally
blues_pal<-blues(500)

## Finally use paste to set transparency to every color in the vector
blues_pal_transp<-paste(blues_pal, "50", sep="")

## and an example
image(volcano, col=blues_pal_transp)
```

Comment: You can also use `paste0` instead of `paste(..., sep='')`